# Print all variables used within a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

Is there any way to print all the variables declared and used within a Bash script?

For example `printf "%s\n" "${FUNCNAME[@]}"` will print the names of all shell functions currently in the execution call stack.

Ex: This is my script content (there must be a lot of declared variables):

```
#!/bin/bash

say_hello() {
    name="$1"
    echo "Hello $name"
}

my_name="Luis Daniel"
my_age="29"

say_hello "$my_name"
```

Then, I need to log something like this:

```
my_name = Luis Daniel
my_age = 29
name = Luis Daniel
```

Comment: @LuisDaniel does the answer given answer your question? Don't forget to accept it using the check mark if so.

Answer (score 8):

The commands `set` or `declare` by themselves will print all shell variables and their values (and would additionally output function definitions). `declare -p` would not output function definitions but would annotate each variable with its type (e.g. `-r` for read-only, `-a` for array, etc.)  The `export` command by itself will print environment variables (exported shell variables), as would `env` and `printenv`.

Whether the variables are *used* or not within the current shell session will not necessarily be detected in the output of these commands.  The `bash` shell has a number of variables that exists in *any* shell session, such as `RANDOM` and `EUID`, regardless of whether these are used or not. A variable may also not be available in the current scope when `declare` is called, for example if it's a local variable in a function, or if it has been `unset`, or if it was declared in a sub-shell that is no longer active.

Would you want to see the variables created in a particular script, you would have to save the output of e.g. `declare -p` at the start of the script and later compare that with another invocation of the same command at the end of the script (or wherever you'd like to investigate the currently declared variables).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=$(mktemp)
declare -p >"$tmpfile"

say_hello() {
    name="$1"
    echo "Hello $name"
}

my_name="Luis Daniel"
my_age="29"

say_hello "$my_name"

declare -p | diff "$tmpfile" -
rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh
Hello Luis Daniel
46c46,49
< declare -- _=""
---
> declare -- _="Luis Daniel"
> declare -- my_age="29"
> declare -- my_name="Luis Daniel"
> declare -- name="Luis Daniel"
```

Note that declaring `name` as a `local` variable in the function would, since it's not available at the second call to `declare -p`, produce

```
Hello Luis Daniel
46c46,48
< declare -- _=""
---
> declare -- _="Luis Daniel"
> declare -- my_age="29"
> declare -- my_name="Luis Daniel"
```